# Two differents splits for two differents slices

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

I make a canvas Discord bot, and I want to do a command like this:
`.igor arg1|arg2|arg3`. Now, as you can see, only the command is separated by a simple space, and args are separated by a vertical bar.

What I did first is this:

```js
let args = message.content.slice(cfg.prefix.length).trim().split(/\|+/g)
```

Here's my code:

```js
client.on("message", function (message) {
if (!message.content.startsWith(cfg.prefix) || message.author.bot) return;
let args = message.content.slice(cfg.prefix.length).trim().split(/+\|+/g)
let command = args.shift().toLowerCase();
  if (command === "igor") {
    console.log(`test: args: ${args} commande: ${command}`);
  }
})
```

See the console log line? I want my console to print `test: args: arg1,arg2,arg3 commande: igor` when I type my command like this: `.igor arg1|arg2|arg3`. If I type this command with the actual code, I have absolutely nothing showing on the console. But, if I type my command like that: `.igor|arg1|arg2|arg3`, the console print the thing that I want. However, I don't want to type my command like that. Who want to type a command like that?

I need to put an another slice and split. But where, and how? Do I really need to put an another slice and split? I don't know anymore.

Comment: Your current regex splits on one or multiple `|` characters, try `/\s|\|/g` to split on a space or a `|`.

Comment: It's working! Thank you so much!!

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution of my problem thanks to [Titus](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1552587/titus): it was my regex.
This was my old regex: `/+\|+/g` and this is my new regex: `/\s|\|/g`
This regex detects space and |. Now, if I type that: `.igor arg1|arg2|arg3`, my console prints this: `test: args: arg1,arg2,arg3 commande: igor` and this is what I want.

But what if I type my command like that: `.igor arg1 | arg2 | arg3`? My console prints this: `test: args: arg1,,,arg2,,,arg3 commande: igor`. The bot thinks that spaces are arguments.

The solution for that is super simple. All I need to do is to add `.filter(Boolean)` at the end of my variable: 
`let args = message.content.slice(cfg.prefix.length).trim().split(/\s|\|/g).filter(Boolean)`. 
Now my console prints this: `test: args: arg1,arg2,arg3 commande: igor`, even if I put millions of spaces between my args.

Happy coding!

Comment: Quantifiers can help match multiple similar character. For example, [`/\s*\|\s*|\s+/g`](https://regex101.com/r/3FbTcb/2) will split at 0 or more whitespace characters before and after (including) a vertical bar, *or* 1 or more of whitespace characters. `*` is the token matching 0 or more. `+` is the token matching 1 or more. Both are greedy, meaning they will continue to capture as much as they can.